# In R $ operator is invalid for atomic vector following subsetting

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a dataframe which I subset into three. In the origional dataframe I can split the data further on a variable, but once I subset it I can no longer do this, with the error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. I am unclear why this is the case, does anyone have any ideas?

I cannot really provide a minimal reproducible example but below is the code used.

```
#Origional dataset = CT_variable_Biom

##First splitting into three categories
CT_variable_Biom <- CT_variable_Biom %>%
  mutate(
    level_of_risk = case_when(
      high_risk == 1 ~ "high",
      medium_risk == 1 ~ "medium",
      low_risk == 1 ~ "low",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_  
    )
  )

medium_risk <- subset(CT_variable_Biom, CT_variable_Biom$level_of_risk=="medium")
high_risk <- subset(CT_variable_Biom, CT_variable_Biom$level_of_risk=="high")
low_risk <- subset(CT_variable_Biom, CT_variable_Biom$level_of_risk=="low")

#Split based on level

#This one works as normal
False_Negatives_overall <- subset(CT_variable_Biom , CT_variable_Biom$Biomarker<0.25)
#This one returns $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
False_Negatives <- subset(medium_risk, medium_risk$Biomarker<0.25)
```

I assume that something in my subseting into the three categories is causing this, but I am not sure what

Many thansk.

Comment: It returns all the variables in the dataset (n=291) including the Biomarker variable

Comment: Typo `CT_variable_Biom $Biomarker`, delete the space?

Comment: Provide example data to reproduce the error.

Comment: not so sure @jay.sf. Try `mtcars $am`

Comment: Show the first 9 lines of the dataset. That might help. `dput( CT_variable_Biom[1:9,])`.  As a good habit: also show the library() statements.

Comment: This is a minimal example.


CT_variable_Biom <- data.frame(
  name          = c( "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"),
  high_risk     = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  medium_risk   = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  low_risk      = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  level_of_risk = c("high", "medium", "high", "low", "medium"),
  Biomarker     = c(0.50, 0.10, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50)
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your dataframe has a column named `medium_risk`.  When you evaluate

```
False_Negatives <- subset(medium_risk, medium_risk$Biomarker<0.25)
```

the `subset()` function needs to evaluate `medium_risk$Biomarker`.  It searches the columns of the dataframe before looking for the global variable `medium_risk`, and it finds the column.  In this case the simplest fix is the one suggested by @clp, i.e. just use

```
False_Negatives <- subset(medium_risk, Biomarker<0.25)
```

In this expression `subset()` will be looking for `Biomarker`, and it finds that column.

This is an example of why the `?subset` documentation says "This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences."

The standard way to do this would be

```
False_Negatives <- medium_risk[medium_risk$Biomarker<0.25, ]
```

and that is unambiguous, because only standard evaluation is used.

Personally I prefer using `subset()`, but I try to avoid using any variables that aren't columns of the dataframe.  It's not always possible to do that; when things are complicated or when I don't have control of the column names, it's better to follow the advice from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
CT_variable_Biom <- data.frame(
  name          = c( "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"),
  high_risk     = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  medium_risk   = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  low_risk      = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  level_of_risk = c("high", "medium", "high", "low", "medium"),
  Biomarker     = c(0.50, 0.10, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50)
)

medium_risk <- subset(CT_variable_Biom, CT_variable_Biom$level_of_risk=="medium")
False_Negatives <- subset(medium_risk, Biomarker<0.25) # <--- solution
```

Confusion arises between the data frame attribute `medium_risk` and the dataset `medium_risk`.

The code below is valid:

```
medium_risk_df  <- subset(CT_variable_Biom, CT_variable_Biom$level_of_risk=="medium")
subset(medium_risk_df, medium_risk_df$Biomarker   < 0.25) # or alternatively
subset(medium_risk_df, Biomarker < 0.25)
```

Comment: if you are using `subset` no need of calling the data twice ie `subset(CT_variable_Biom, level_of_risk=="medium")` should work